# How to determine if ViewState has MAC enabled when crawling a page?

Tags: asp.net, security, viewstate

I was using [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to do some security testing on a site and I noticed that when it detects ViewState it will automatically tell you whether it has MAC enabled.

I'm curious if anyone know of a programatic way to determine if MAC is enabled if you are crawling a site without actually attempting to modify the ViewState, submit it and see if anything blows up?

From what I can tell Burp Suite is doing this just by look at the request (and not modifying/submitting).

Comment: Cross posting between stackexchange sites is highly discouraged http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-determine-if-viewstate-has-mac-enabled-when-crawling-a-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ViewStates are basically BASE64 encoded strings. So what you can do is try to decode them with a BASE64 decoder. If it's encrypted you will get some binary content which is not really readable. If no encryption is used you will be able to see the contents. For instance [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com) can assist you in decoding ViewStates in your browser.

Now there is also the option of using a MAC:

> If the viewstate has its MAC enabled then there  The security of this
>   system lies in the secrecy of the secret key value. This value is
>   always stored on the server, either in memory or in a configuration
>   file (more on this later)—it is never written to the page. Without
>   knowing the key, there would be no way for an attacker to compute a
>   valid view state hash.

from [MSDN "View State Security"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797918.aspx).

You can check this by decoding the VIEWSTATE (if not encrypted) and verify if a 20-byte hash is present at the end of the ViewState structure.